# How do I get the Twitter Tools widget to display my tweets?

Tags: plugins, twitter

I'm trying to archive my tweets in Wordpress and display recent ones in my sidebar. I've installed the Twitter Tools plugin, configured it, and added its widget to my sidebar. Twitter Tools is creating blog posts for each of my tweets, so I know it is authorized by Twitter successully. However, the sidebar widget just displays "No tweets available at the moment."

I've tried the procedure [described here](http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/wordpress/a-perfect-integration-of-wordpress-and-twitter/) to uninstall and reinstall Twitter Tools to no avail.

I'm also using the Ultimate Category Excluder plugin to exclude the tweet posts from my feed and homepage. I'm worried that might be the problem but others seem to be using this setup successfully. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging on this and I found that the Twitter Tools widget depends on a table called wp_ak_twitter. I didn't have this table, probably because my Wordpress database user doesn't have create table privileges. I create the table by hand and now the widget is working.

Answer (score 1):

**@Ben,**
It could be a problem with Twitter's new Oauth rules that went into effect on August 31st.  Alex updated the plugin to work with Oauth but I am hearing a lot of people are having problems with it.

Are you running the latest version of the plugin? Have you set up your Twitter app and api key?

Also to note that php5 is required.

Comment: I'm running Wordpress 3.0.1, Twitter Tools 2.4, PHP 5.2.4. I did the Twitter app and api key, and I think that is working since Twitter Tools creates blog posts from my tweets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a problem with your excluder setup.  As you say the fact that the blog posts are being created demonstrates the successful connection to twitter.

I would disable the excluder plugin and force it to manually update on the twitter tools settings page.  If your tweets show then I would re-enable the plugin and work within its settings to correct the problem.

MM/RC

Comment: Good suggestion but deactivating Ultimate Category Excluder made no difference.